# How can I clear Integer EditText android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I bring data from EditText then convert it to integer but I want button for clear EditText, I did this fir do some operations

```
        Integer m = Integer.parseInt(edt_MoneyAmount.getText().toString());
```

---

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_W_moneyAmount"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="المبلغ"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.88"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.246" />
```

I tried this for clear:

```
edt_MoneyAmount.setText("0");
```

this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

I think can't use it because I converted to integer.

help me pls

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your whole declaration of this **EditText** in xml?

Because I created on my own something like this

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="12344"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And I can change its text by

```
        editText.setText("0")

and 
        editText.setText("")
```

You are getting this crash because you are use this operation on empty EditText text value

```
        Integer m = Integer.parseInt(edt_MoneyAmount.getText().toString());
```

Comment: @younismohamed Updated my response. 
You are getting this error because you are trying to use 
        Integer m = Integer.parseInt(edt_MoneyAmount.getText().toString());
 on an empty EditText.

If you will really set value to 0 then everything will be good

Comment: I don't understand I should put    ex.setText("0");   before convert edittext to Integer and after do operation put  ex.setText("");